# How to allow USPS shipping method for all products?

Tags: magento2, shipping, usps

I am new to Magento and want to set USPS shipping charge for all products.
 Currently, it is visible for those products which have weight.
How can I do this? Am I missing any configuration?

Comment: why not set the Maximum Package weight to **'0'** , then it should work to every product i

Comment: it is not working

Comment: how about trying to set to Yes, Show Method if Not Applicable? I think this will bypass the conditions

Comment: that will disable the method and I want to calculate USPS shipping charge for each products but may be there is no way instead I have to set weight for all products

Comment: yeah, I think that could be the best thing to do but it's too much inconvenience on our side.

Comment: yeah, I don't know but there should be some code modification where Magento check for product's weight

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically You can allow this method based on country. The reason why it appear only to products which have weight because Magento sends weight information to UPS and USPS

[image]

**Specify Allowed Methods and Applicable Countries**

1. In the Allowed Methods list, choose each USPS shipping method to be available to your customers. The methods appear under USPS during checkout. (Hold the Ctrl key down to select multiple options). Then, do the following:

   a. Set the Free Method list to the method you want to use for free shipping. If you don’t want to offer free shipping through USPS, choose “None.”

   b. In the Free Shipping Amount  Threshold field, enter the minimum amount that qualifies an order for free shipping with USPS.
2. The Displayed Error Message text box is preset with a default message. You can either leave this message or enter the message that you want to appear if USPS becomes unavailable.

[image]

3. Set Ship to Applicable Countries to one of the following:

**All Allowed Countries**

Customers from all countries specified in your store configuration can use this shipping method.

**Specific Countries**

After choosing this option, the Ship to Specific Countries list appears. Select each country in the list where this shipping method can be used.

[image]

4. Set Show Method if Not Applicable to one of the following:

**Yes**

Lists all available USPS shipping methods during checkout, including those that don’t apply to the shipment.

**No**

Lists only the USPS shipping methods that are applicable to the shipment.

For more details of configuration of USPS check the  reference: https://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/shipping/usps.html

Comment: so if the reason is `Maximum Package Weight` than why should I choose each USPS shipping method? my configuration is https://pasteboard.co/I68GjUF.png and `all allowed countries` is selected in applicable countries @MuhammadHasham

Comment: What I actually meant as far as I know Magento sends weight information to UPS and USPS. Another good detail knowledge configuration https://www.simicart.com/blog/magento-usps/

Comment: You have to specify products weight In support of my claim check the reference https://www.theedigital.com/blog/setting-up-magento-with-usps

Comment: my bad it does not work

Comment: solution is as said in doc, product weight is compulsory. I accepted your answer but may be it will not display publicly @muhammadHasham

Comment: ok, I have accepted